# How to allow all Outlook users to Use MS OAuth2

Tags: oauth-2.0, azure-devops, azure-active-directory

I have created one application where I am using MS oauth2. But It's allowing only my Azure AD user to use MS auth. I want to make it available for all outlook users. So what changes I need to made in manifest or any other file in Azure?

I am Getting below screen after login using any other outlook account:

[image]

Comment: Which oauth2 flow you are trying [Microsoft Authentication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v1-oauth2-client-creds-grant-flow)

Comment: I am using this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-v2-protocols

Comment: I see, which specific flow you are using among them?

Comment: I am using v2-oauth2-auth-code-flow

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-auth-code-flow

Comment: Do you want to get token using [authorization code flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-auth-code-flow)?

Comment: Take a look. I have successfully reproduce your problem. See the solution. If you still have any problem just let me know. Thanks and happy coding! –

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What changes I need to made in manifest or any other file in Azure?

It seems you are having trouble with `personal@outlook.com` account while login `azure portal tenant`

**Error You Have Encountered :**

I have successfully reproduce your problem. See the screen shot below:

[image]

**Reason Of Error:**

The email account you are trying to log in with. Is not exist on your current tenant.

**Resolution:**

Go to your tenant where you would like to add your `example.outlook.com` account to login into and follow below steps:

1. Azure portal
2. Azure Active Directory
3. Users
4. New Guest User
5. Put Your `example@outlook.com` email
6. Invite

See the screen shot below:

[image]

**Issue Solution and Test:**

After above steps I have successfully login with `example@outlook.com`. See the screen shot below:

[image]

**Access Code:**

[image]

**Access Token With Code:**

[image]

Decode Token:

You can decode your token on [`https://jwt.io/`](https://jwt.io/)

See the screen shot below:

[image]

**Note:** Once you successfully add your `example.outlook.com` email account on your tenant you can get your token with login.

Comment: Thanks !! Got my mistake

Comment: Hi there. I wonder if I could point out that quote blocks are not intended to be used as a general block-level highlighter. This formatting has a special semantic meaning - it is used to signify that something is a quote, i.e. someone (a person) or something (a book or manual) said/contained the thing being quoted. It is misleading to highlight your own voice with a quote block, because readers will wonder who said it (and why the source has not been cited).